# How to reuse vue method for different form inputs

Tags: vue.js, methods

I am making a gaming character creator menu, which has a lot of form inputs that essentialy work the same way, incrementing an attribute up or down by one on button click.

I am fairly new to using Vue and would like to be able to pass the character attribute eg. 'torso' aswell from the form element to my increase() and decrease() methods without to repeat code.  Currently I can change by hardcoding in the this.form.heads++ or this.form.heads-- but would like to do something like this.form.val++ with val being which ever form element was clicked.

index.html

```
<form>
    <div class="attr_block">
        <div class="attr_row">
            <div class="attr-col">
                <label class="attr_label">Head Type</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-col center">
                <div class="left_arrow" @click="decrease()"></div>
                <label class="attr_label">Type {{form.heads}}</label>
                <div class="right_arrow" @click="increase()"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="attr_row">
            <div class="attr-col">
                <label class="attr_label">Torso Type</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-col center">
                <div class="left_arrow" @click="decrease()"></div>
                <label class="attr_label">Type {{form.torso}}</label>
                <div class="right_arrow" @click="increase()"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

app.js (cut down a little to focus on the issue)

````
const APP = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    step:1,
    display: false,
    form: {
      albedo:'mp_head_mr1_sc08_c0_000_ab',
      heads:1,
      torse:1,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    OpenUI() {
      this.display = true
    },
    CloseUI() {
      this.display = false
      $.post('https://parks_creator/CloseUI')
    },
    decrease(){
      this.form.heads--;
      $.post('https://parks_creator/inputchange', JSON.stringify({
          data: this.form        
      }))
    },
    increase(){
      this.form.heads++;
      $.post('https://parks_creator/inputchange', JSON.stringify({
          data: this.form        
      }))
    },
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
    change(){
      $.post('https://parks_creator/inputchange', JSON.stringify({
          data: this.form        
      }))
    },
  },
  computed: {},
  watch: {

  },
  
})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a character attribute to your methods as a parameter.

script:

```
methods: {
  decrease(attribute){
    this.form[attribute]--
  },

  increase(attribute){
    this.form[attribute]++
  }
}
```

template

```
<div @click="increase('heads')" />
<div @click="decrease('heads')" />

<div @click="increase('torso')" />
<div @click="decrease('torso')" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, code will be much cleaner thanks to you.